# my django query: how to improve the speed of list view

Tags: python, django, performance, optimization

List page is paginated and displaying only 10 journal posts. Despite this, there are 95 queries being performed. It's affecting the page load speed. Instead of loading <1 second it's taking around 4-5 seconds.
Here are my code, please check and let me know how to optimize.
views.py

```
class PostListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Post
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(PostListView, self).get_queryset().filter(Q(
            Q(language_id__in=self.request.user.native_language),
            ~Q(user_id__in=self.request.user.forbidden_user_list))).order_by('-created')
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['list_type'] = 'all'
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    text = models.TextField()
    native_text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, db_index=True)
    # updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    # is_corrected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    users_like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='posts_liked',
                                        blank=True)
    language = models.ForeignKey('account.Language', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    @property
    def get_correctors(self):
        from account.models import Profile as User
        result = list(set(User.objects.all().filter((Q(correctedrows__post_id=self.id) | Q(perfectrows__post_id=self.id) | Q(comment__post_id=self.id)))))
        return result
```

Comment: possible you use the property `get_correctors` in your html and of course it generate new queries.

Comment: try to use the https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html to see more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `get_queryset` method, you should try to use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to get whatever you will use in your template.

For example, if in your template you are doing `post.user.name`, that is going to cause an additional query. Try something like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(PostListView, self).get_queryset().select_related('user', 'language'). prefetch_related('users_like').filter(Q(
            Q(language_id__in=self.request.user.native_language),
            ~Q(user_id__in=self.request.user.forbidden_user_list))).order_by('-created')
        return qs
```

Comment: have you ever compared the result of both with time seconds?